# element not interactable in Selenium, when using CSS Selector, why only XPath?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I recently started some experiments with Selenium in C# and I came accross the exception:
`element not interactable` when trying to use the `SendKeys`, using the following `By.CssSelector`:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
IWebElement elementByCss = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.Ax4B8.ZAGvjd"));
elementByCss.SendKeys("MyKeys");
```

However, many answers on Stackoverflow suggest to use the `By.XPath` instead. In fact the following version does work:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
IWebElement elementByXpath = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/div/div[2]/span/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/input[2]")); 
elementByXpath.SendKeys("MyKeys");
```

For maintainability i'd actually would prefer the version with the CSS selector.
I can tell that `string cssClass = elementByXpath.GetAttribute("class");` would actually have the correct classes.
Anyhow the `IWebElement` have different IDs which I honestly don't understand why.

Here is a snippet of the (Google Photos) HTML code

```
<div class="L6J0Pc VOEIyf LAL5ie cI2tlc" jscontroller="Mq9n0c" jsaction="keydown:I481le; focus: AHmuwe;AHmuwe:AHmuwe; mouseenter:npT2md;Mu8aMc:YPqjbf;Edq9ub:SDqDXe;e0gSlf:pX1iqf;" data-persist-on-navigation="true" data-close-on-blur="true" jsname="s514wb" data-renderer="p1EOdb" data-service="pv5rLb" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="d1dlne" jscontroller="K99qY" jsname="YPqjbf" style="position: relative" data-placeholder="In deinen Fotos suchen" data-showselected="false" aria-disabled="false" jslog="9602; track:click,keyboard_enter" data-expanded="false">
        <input class="yNVtPc ZAGvjd Ny5lGc" disabled="true" aria-hidden="true" jsname="A51lKb" value="In deinen Fotos suchen"/>
        <input class="Ax4B8 ZAGvjd" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-label="In deinen Fotos suchen" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" jsname="dSO9oc" jsaction="input:YPqjbf; keydown:I481le; click:cOuCgd" size="1" aria-owns="nngdp193" aria-controls="nngdp193" dir="ltr"/>
    </div>
    <div class=" tWfTvb">
        <div class="u3WVdc jBmls" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" data-expanded="false" data-childcount="0" jsname="iuXDpb" jsaction="mousedown:npT2md(preventDefault=true);" jslog="9605; track:impression" id="nngdp193" style="max-height: 1263px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I see in your xPath you have `input[2]`, indicating the second input element under that path. My question, since the css selector can be applied to multiple elements, which one should the SendKeys call interact with?

Comment: @quaabaam I updated the post and added a part of the HTML. The second input seems to be right (especially because elementByXpath.GetAttribute("class") returns "Ax4B8 ZAGvjd" in the working version by XPath. No glue at all. Checking many StackOverflow articels, most peope recommend to use XPath to avoid the error, still "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/div/div[2]/span/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/input[2]" is not my favorite way to go